# Problemas ao submeter formulários com várias linhas

Tags: php

Preciso de uma luz, pois, estou a dias tentando entender esse raciocínio do Array no PHP. Segue minha dor de cabeça:

```
<div class="content">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>OBS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            $sql = mysqli_query($conexaoDados, "SELECT * FROM usuariosBD ORDER BY id DESC");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="key[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subnome[]" value="<?php echo $row['sobrenome']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="obs[]" value="<?php echo $row['obs']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            }}
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submiting">Salvar dados</button>
</form>
```

No exemplo acima, terei estes dados:

```
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="key[]" value="123" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" value="Luiz" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subnome[]" value="Aurelio" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="obs[]" value="Usuário premium a partir de Setembro." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="key[]" value="124" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" value="Amós" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subnome[]" value="Bernadinho da Silva" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="obs[]" value="Usuário comum a partir de Janeiro." /></td>
            </tr>
```

Ao montar o PHP, fiz desta forma:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submiting'])) {
    $inputs = array(
    'ID'    =>  $_POST['key'],
    'NOME'  =>  $_POST['nome'],
    'SUB'   =>  $_POST['subnome'],
    'OBS'   =>  $_POST['obs']
    );

    foreach($inputs as $row) {
        echo $row['ID'];
        echo $row['NOME'];
        echo $row['SUB'];
        echo $row['OBS'];
    }
}
```

?>

Infelizmente, ele não retorna nada, visto que eles existem. Alguém poderia me explicar onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está atribuindo a chave ao VALOR. Não existe essa chave neste valor. Sua chave teria que ser atribuída ao array `$input`. Veja:

```
print_r($inputs["ID"]); // isso funciona

foreach($inputs as $key => $row) {
    print_r($row[$key]); // isso não funciona
    print_r($row["ID"]); // isso não funciona
    print_r($inputs[$key]); // isso funciona
}
```

Eu não vejo necessidade de inserir cada $_POST em um único array, visto que esses `$_POSTs` já são um array. Então acredito que é mais fácil você fazer assim:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submiting'])) {

    for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['key']); $x++){
       echo $_POST['key'][$x];
       echo $_POST['nome'][$x];
       echo $_POST['subnome'][$x];
       echo $_POST['obs'][$x];
    }
}
```

Você consegue fazer isso:

```
if(isset($_POST['submiting'])) {
    $inputs = array(
        'ID'    =>  $_POST['key'],
        'NOME'  =>  $_POST['nome'],
        'SUB'   =>  $_POST['subnome'],
        'OBS'   =>  $_POST['obs']
    );


    foreach($inputs as $row) {
        foreach($row as $r){
            echo $r."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Mas acho que é redundante.

Comment: obrigado. Você deixou claro e também me solucionou a dúvida. :D Abraços.

Comment: @Robson tranquilo... Inclusive eu estava me confundindo! Quase fui procurar um curso de php pra mim. rsrs.. Abraço!